# Can someone check if I answered this probability question correctly?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Consider a six-sided die that is loaded so that numbers 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 are
all equally likely to appear, and 1 is three times as likely to appear as 2.
(a) What is the probability of rolling a 2?
(b) What is the probability of rolling a 1?
(c) What is the probability of rolling an even number?

a) 1/8
b) 3/8
c) 3/8

Is it that simple? I feel like there is something I am missing.

Comment: You are all right. It's as simple. No worries there.